# How can I allow a user to get access to survey results using the Google Consumer Surveys API?

Tags: google-api, google-surveys

I’ve created a survey using [Google Consumer Surveys](https://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/home). I want use a different account to check results of the survey.

How do I allow a second google account to access the survey though the API?

Comment: sidenote: @DanHolvevoet Can you chime in [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327707/reachout-to-google-regarding-consumer-surveys#327707)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second account by modifying the owners of a survey.

You can do this through the UI by selecting a survey from your list of surveys and then clicking the +Share button in the top right hand corner of the page. Then put the email address of the new owner in.

https://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/

You can also do this programatically through the API by issuing an update call to the Survey resource with a new Owners list. Note that this overwrites the owners field and does not append to it, so make sure to include the current owners when issuing an update so that no one losses access. You can find the documentation for this here:

https://developers.google.com/consumer-surveys/v2/reference/surveys/update